# Add info to the info box of a dygraph with the relevant R package

Tags: r, data.table, data-visualization, r-dygraphs

```
#libraries
library(data.table)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

#dummy data
dates <- data.table(dates  = seq.Date(as.Date("2017-03-01"), length = 14, by = "month"),
                    satisfaction = runif(14, min = 0.1, max = 1),
                    answers = runif(14, min = 100, max = 1000),
                    )

#convert to xts
xts_dates <- xts(dates, order.by = as.POSIXct(dates$dates, format = ("%Y-%m-%d")))
dygraph(xts_dates)
```

I want only to plot `satisfaction` and add the `answers` data either to the info box on the top right corner or elsewhere where it's visible
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#libraries
library(data.table)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

#dummy data
dates <- data.table(dates  = seq.Date(as.Date("2017-03-01"), length = 14, by = "month"),
                    satisfaction = runif(14, min = 0.1, max = 1),
                    answers = runif(14, min = 100, max = 1000)
                    )

#convert to xts
xts_dates <- xts(dates, order.by = as.POSIXct(dates$dates, format = ("%Y-%m-%d")))
xts_dates <- xts_dates[, 2:3]

#create dygraph with double axes
dygraph(xts_dates, main = "Satisfaction") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Satisfaction") %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label = "Number of answers", independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dySeries("answers", axis = 'y2')
```

Basically, I added an additional axis for number of answers.[image]